# I have a trouble with data in app

Tags: android

I create a simple app for Android with question and answers.
Below that look my data question right now:

```
private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
        new Question(R.string.question_a1, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_a2, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_a3, false),
        new Question(R.string.question_a4, true),
        new Question(R.string.question_a5, true),
};
```

This code place in QuestionActivity (as MainActivity).
But I have a second activity - HintActivity.
HintActivity include button, onClick function, and answer for every question that I have.

Now it realize like that:

```
mShowAnswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
            mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
        } else {
            mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
        }
```

So it get boolean info from mQuestionBank and write true or false.
But I want to get another question data.
Example: `R.string.question_a1_answer`

My question: How change question data that I may add answer strings and get it on HintActivity?

Comment: What does the boolean value in `new Question(R.string.question_a1, true)` mean?